# modern pure code way to external JS file used in svg file without xlink

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I try to find a way to outsource my javascript code from an svg file which is used to make it interactive useable via embed tag in a html 5 document.

And yes there is xlink.
BUT I hope there is a validating way which is more modern than this.

I could not find such a way in the specification at https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/ or https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/.

But is this really the newest standard for svg ? Are there no newer informations than 2011 ? And if not: Is it possible to use something like  ?

I do not want to use any frameworks, extensions, hacks or alike.
The code should be validating, easy to understand and short.

Oh and here some code to show what I mean / have done so far:

htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>start</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/design.css">
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head><body>
<header><h1>Test</h1></header>
<section>
 <article id="Start">
<embed id="svg" src="pics/SVG1.svg">
 </article>
</section>
<footer id="startfooter">2016</footer>
</body></html>
```

svg:

```
<svg id="svg2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600px" height="430px">
<title>SVG 1</title>
<desc>My Pic</desc>
<defs></defs>
<script xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" type="application/ecmascript">
 <![CDATA[
function setz(elem,Farbe) {
var das= document.getElementById(elem);
das.setAttribute("style", Farbe);
}
// ...
 ]]>
</script>
<rect x="0" y="0"  width="600" height="430" fill="white" />
 <g>
<svg x="10" y="265" width="50" height="50">
<rect x="0" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" width="50" height="50" style="fill:white; stroke:black; stroke-width:2px;" />
<text x="5" y="30" width="10" onclick="setz('test','fill:red;')">
Rechts</text>
</svg>
<rect id="test" x="200" y="265"  width="60" height="43" fill="black" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

Help would be nice.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your problem is.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  Can you attempt to state it in different terms?

Comment: I would like to explain it in another way, if I had a guess what exactly is not clear...

To use something like <script src="js/main.js"></script> directly in the svg would be my aim.

So everthing in script could be used in several svg files. BUT to refer on an standard from 1999 feels just not very modern. AND it would be two long additions to the svg code if xlink is used.

Comment: I am using modern HTML 5 so I write <!DOCTYPE html> instead of <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">. Also I do not use style anymore because I can use a CSS stylesheet.

So why should I have to use <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> to be allowed to use <script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="myscript.js" /> ?

Isn't there a shorter more up to date way ?
(And yes my main problem here is to load an extension for something svg should be capable to do by itself... Or did I got it wrong?)

Comment: Nothing? Am I the only one interrested in this?